# Установка GDevelop на ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, chmod

Захотел посмотреть что такое GDevelop 5 - скачал файл с офиц. сайта. Выпольнил команду `chmod a+x GDevelop-5-5.0.0-beta97.AppImage` , как сказано на офиц. сайте. После этого выполнил `./GDevelop-5-5.0.0-beta97.AppImage`, но выдается ошибка
`bash: ./GDevelop-5-5.0.0-beta97.AppImage: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Битность приложения и системы не совпадают.

Comment: битность системы я знаю, а где узнать битность приложения?

Comment: @Nezerix утилита `file`

Comment: Какая конкретно утилита? Я просто не разбираюсь.

Comment: @Nezerix `file ./GDevelop-5-5.0.0-beta97.AppImage`

Comment: Проверил - вы правы!